# Conditions for statespace statsmodel mlemodel

Tags: python, statsmodels, bayesian, kalman-filter, state-space

I'm trying to run a TVP VAR on Statsmodel for a Big Data, but there seems to be a problem when trying to validate the vector matrix and the vector shape. Especially when defining the start and update parameter , mostly on the dimension and the structure of the update parameters. My model is a TVP-PVAR in a normal linear state space model composed of the State Equation eand the Measurement Equation. . There is a large amount of data, therefore I'm using numerous variables in the model. My model equations are:

[image]

Where X ̃t=XtΞ and ut=Xt′+ut with Ut∼N(0,(I+σ2Xt′Xt))×Σ

My issues that cannot solve are that I have specified k_states=702, which means the state_cov matrix must be 702 x 702. In the update method, I'm trying to set the state_cov to be a 3x3 matrix, which is wrong. The error is telling me that the state_cov cannot be a 3x3 matrix. Desired is a 702 x 702 matrix , a k_states x k_states, if I get this right. I so not get where this 3X3 came from

I have two questions:

How could I correct the full code, or how could I modify properly my code in order to get the right results? I cannot see where and how set up the state_cov matrix to be 702x702

Since this is a TVP-VAR, and unit root is assumed, my understanding is that I have to keep only the " diffuse''and remove the "stationarity " . Same goes for "constrain_stationary_multivariate" and "unconstrain_stationary_multivariate". Am I getting this right? Much appreciate a full version of the code!

**`Traceback** :

```
    `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/user/Documents/PYTHON/Spider/tvp/tvpstandard5.py", line 246, in <module>
    preliminary = mod.fit(maxiter=1000)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 704, in fit
    mlefit = super(MLEModel, self).fit(start_params, method=method,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 563, in fit
    xopt, retvals, optim_settings = optimizer._fit(f, score, start_params,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py", line 241, in _fit
    xopt, retvals = func(objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py", line 651, in _fit_lbfgs
    retvals = optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, start_params, maxiter=maxiter,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 197, in fmin_l_bfgs_b
    res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 306, in _minimize_lbfgsb
    sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 261, in _prepare_scalar_function
    sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._update_fun()

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 233, in _update_fun
    self._update_fun_impl()

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 137, in update_fun
    self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 134, in fun_wrapped
    return fun(np.copy(x), *args)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 531, in f
    return -self.loglike(params, *args) / nobs

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 933, in loglike
    self.update(params, transformed=True, includes_fixed=True,

  File "/Users/user/Documents/PYTHON/Spider/tvp/tvpstandard5.py", line 218, in update
    self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 239, in __setitem__
    return self.ssm.__setitem__(key, value)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/representation.py", line 420, in __setitem__
    setattr(self, key, value)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/representation.py", line 54, in __set__
    value = self._set_matrix(obj, value, shape)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/representation.py", line 68, in _set_matrix
    validate_matrix_shape(

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/tools.py", line 1474, in validate_matrix_shape
    raise ValueError('Invalid dimensions for %s matrix: requires %d'

ValueError: Invalid dimensions for state covariance matrix matrix: requires 702 rows, got 3``
```

**Code**

```
`
class TVPVAR(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):


                    
    
def __init__(self, y):
    # Create a matrix with [y_t' : y_{t-1}'] for t = 2, ..., T
    augmented = sm.tsa.lagmat(y, 1, trim='both', original='in', use_pandas=True)
    # Separate into y_t and z_t = [1 : y_{t-1}']
  
    p = y.shape[1]
    y_t = augmented.iloc[:, :p]
    z_t = sm.add_constant(augmented.iloc[:, p:])
    nobs = y.shape[0]
    T=y.shape[0]
     
    # Recall that the length of the state vector is p * (p + 1)
    k_states = p * (p + 1)
    super(TVPVAR,self).__init__(y_t, exog=None, k_states=k_states,k_posdef=k_states)

    
    self.k_y = p
    self.k_states = p * (p + 1)  
    self.nobs = T  
    self['design'] = np.zeros((self.k_y, self.k_states, 1))  
    
    self['transition'] = np.eye(k_states) # G
    self['selection'] = np.eye(k_states) # R=1
    
 
    
def update_variances(self, obs_cov, state_cov_diag):
    self['obs_cov'] = obs_cov
    self['state_cov'] = np.diag(state_cov_diag)    # W
    init = initialization.Initialization(self.k_states)
    init.set((0, 2), 'diffuse')
    init.set((2, 4), 'stationary')
    self.ssm.initialize(init)
     

     

def constrain_stationary_multivariate(unconstrained, variance,
                                  transform_variance=False,
                                  prefix=None):
  
    
  unconstrained =np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y * order)
  variance=np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y)
   
  order  = k_y
  
  prefix = find_best_blas_type(
        [unconstrained, variance])
  dtype = prefix_dtype_map[prefix]

  unconstrained = np.asfortranarray(unconstrained, dtype=dtype)
  variance = np.asfortranarray(variance, dtype=dtype)
  # Step 1: convert from arbitrary matrices to those with singular values
  # less than one.
  # sv_constrained = _constrain_sv_less_than_one(unconstrained, order,
  #                                              k_y, prefix)

  sv_constrained = prefix_sv_map[prefix](unconstrained, order, k_y)
  # Step 2: convert matrices from our "partial autocorrelation matrix"
  # space (matrices with singular values less than one) to the space of
  # stationary coefficient matrices
  constrained, variance = prefix_pacf_map[prefix](
    sv_constrained, variance, transform_variance, order, k_y)

  constrained = np.zeros_like(constrained, dtype=dtype)
  variance = np.zeros_like(variance, dtype=dtype)

  return constrained, variance
  

def unconstrain_stationary_multivariate(constrained, error_variance):
   
   constrained= np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y * order)
   error_variance=np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y)
   # Step 1: convert matrices from the space of stationary
# coefficient matrices to our "partial autocorrelation matrix" space
# (matrices with singular values less than one)
   partial_autocorrelations = _compute_multivariate_pacf_from_coefficients(
    constrained, error_variance, order, k_y)
   unconstrained = _unconstrain_sv_less_than_one(
    partial_autocorrelations, order, k_y)
   return unconstrained, error_variance
  
    
  
def update(self, params, **kwargs):
    params = super().update(params, **kwargs)
    self['transition', 2,2] = params[0]
    self['transition', 3,2] = params[1]
    self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W



@property
def state_names(self):
    state_names = np.empty((self.k_y, self.k_y + 1), dtype=object)
    for i in range(self.k_y):
        endog_nam
```

I have two questions:

How could I correct the full code, or how could I modify properly my code in order to get the right results? I cannot see where and how to set up the state_cov matrix to be 702x702

Since this is a TVP-VAR, and unit root is assumed, my understanding is that I have to keep only the " diffuse''and remove the "stationarity " . Same goes for "constrain_stationary_multivariate" and "unconstrain_stationary_multivariate". Am I getting this right? Much appreciate a full version of the code!

I have debugged, and the error shows up in

self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W

```
after it calls the 
 





 validate_matrix_shape() in tools.py.
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I have debugged, and the error shows up in 

   

 

    self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W
    
    after it calls the 
     
    
       
    
         validate_matrix_shape() in tools.py.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])
```

You're calling the function np.diag(). According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html), when np.diag() is given a 1-D vector of N elements, it creates an NxN matrix, with the element of the vector along the diagonal. You gave it three elements, so it creates a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/users/530160/nick-odell. I can now see a bit clear. 
I am supposed to write this part of the code according to the update method here in the tutorial in part 9 and in the Step4 of part 7 in the link below
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_tvpvar_mcmc_cfa.html
Question is since I am new into python trying to figure out, how could I write correctly my code according to the linked tutorial above now that the error has been spotted ?

Comment: @HelenA Well, I don't know what your covariance matrix ought to be. I know it ought to be 702x702 in terms of shape, but that tells me very little. I can tell you that you can make an 702x702 matrix of all zero using `np.zeros((702, 702))`.